# Is mutableCopy call returns an array with a copy of the managed object context?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

In a tutorial i'm learning CoreData from the preform something like this to fetch the collection of notes in a notes app:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Note"];

    self.notes = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

So first of all, `notes` is an NSMutableArray, so tell me if I understand it right:

1. they creating an NSManagedObjectContext object to hold the context.
2. they create a request to get the "Note" entity from the database file.
3. they use the managedObjectContext to call executeFetchRequest with the requested request (which is fetchRequest). Now here is the part I dont completely understand (probably some of the previous ones as well, please correct me if I didn't):

The type of object i'm getting from this call `[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];` is an NSSet? and by calling `mutableCopy` i'm returning an array?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil]
```

returns an (immutable) `NSArray`, and `mutableCopy` creates a - well - mutable copy 
of that array. It does not copy the managed objects in the array or the context.
It just allows you to modify `self.notes`, e.g. to add, delete or rearrange the objects
in the mutable array.

*Remark:* If you display objects from a Core Data fetch request in a table view
then you should have a look at `NSFetchedResultsController`. It might look a bit more
complicated at the beginning, but allows (for example) automatic updates of the 
table view if objects are inserted, deleted or modified.

Comment: Yes, i'v heard about NSFetchResultController and this is the next step after will get my head around the basic. So basically the array im getting from the call `[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil]` is an array that holds all the records that has been saved by me to the file, right? @Martin R

Comment: @SQS: Yes, it holds an array with all objects of the "Note" entity. You can also add a *predicate* to the fetch request to fetch only objects that satisfies some condition.